# Facebook ‘games’ which are just generated images - how are they done?

Tags: facebook

Apologies if this isn’t a fit for StackOverflow, but I’m interested in creating a Facebook ‘game’ which simply generates an image and let’s users share it. See my picture below as an example.

How is this done? All the resources I find are related to Unity, surely this is overkill for something so simple? I’d like to use C# ideally but willing to try anything else.[image: Example game]

Comment: This looks like an “Instant Game”, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games

Comment: You are very right - thank you!